# What is an effective way to teach children the Cartesian coordinates?

Tags: soft-question, education, coordinate-systems

My nephew is preparing for a $4$-th grade state test. They need to learn topics like reflection about $x$ or $y$-axis of a point( say $(3,5)$ reflected about the $y$-axis).

I tried to explain but he's not getting it. He's smart, but very distracted. How can I explain in an intuitive way?

Comment: Cartesian coordinates in 4-th grade? Isn't that too much for a 4-th grade kid? Is the state test some kind of olympiad?

Comment: @BeniBogosel - Admittedly, it's towards the end of the sample test. And it isn't tested as much as basic arithmetic........ *but* - 4th graders are 8 and 9 years of age. They have decent minds, so Why not?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the ['Battleship game'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battleship_%28game%29) (or other) and put (virtual) boats in the four quarters to get his attention. Because the pleasure of sinking is great! :-)
Introduce horizontal and vertical mirrors if needed (and/or negative coordinates) explaining that the boats are seen or not in mirrors.

Comment: The chess board also woks nicely for this.

Comment: +1 because I love that game... :) and yes, a very nice example.

Comment: @J.M.: Thanks J.M.! Battleship and Chess are great games and only few kids could resist to the pleasure of sinking your boats! :-)

Answer (score 5):

I would say something like "Starting at the origin, $(3,5)$ means go $3$ units to the right (the $x$ direction), and then $5$ units up (in the $y$ direction).  If you reflect about the $y$-axis, you have to go $3$ units to the *left* and then $5$ up, i.e. you're at the point $(-3,5)$.

Hopefully that helps.  When I was learning it helped me to think of the Cartesian plane as a map I had to naviagate

Comment: Thank You Very Much - I like this a lot, it's like a "treasure map" analogy

Comment: @Adel, you have to make sure that he understands *relative* numbers well. You might start with the number line taking his street as model. With his house as the origin, +3 is three houses down and -4 is four houses up.